# Colorbar and most discriminative colors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure, color-scheme

I have a 2D image and I want to visualize it in color (R,G,B). For that purpose I extend the 2D image to 3D where each pixel holds the color value. Now I have read in the hot colormap:

```
temp = figure(1);
clf;
colormap hot;
axis('image');
colorbar;
hot_cmap = colormap;
close(temp);
```

So hot_cmap is now a matrix 64x3 where each row contains one color.

To make the color more distinguishable I'm cutting hot_cmap at the beginning and end (black and white) and also cut some rows in between, so that I have a matrix of 20x3 in the end. Then I map each entry of my 2D matrix to a row of my new color matrix to pick that color.

Additionally I also want to show a colorbar. How can I do this with my new color matrix? The first row of my new color matrix should be the lowest value in the colorbar with a value of 0 and the last row the highest value of 2.

Second, I want a color matrix which has 20 most discriminative colors. Does something like that exist? Of course I can create each color value by myself but this is cumbersome.

Comment: To show an image in color you might just want to go with `imagesc(); colormap  hot`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I want to use a subset of the colours or a set of most distinguishable colors. The colors in the hot colormap are not that distinguishable. And then I want to display the colorbar right.

Comment: Then create your own colormap and do `colormap(mycmap)`

Comment: Re: the last comment by @AnderBiguri, [`colormapeditor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html) might be helpful. Also, I believe that part of the idea behind the new [`parula` colormap](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/colormap/) in R2014b+ is better discrimination.

Comment: And if you want even better colormaps check this: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps